# Update part of text inside a text column (array structure) in Postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Here is my problem. I have a table similar to this.

In the parameters i want to change the default value where the expression is date_from and date_until.

How can i work my way into this array and just change this two values while ignoring the rest of the text?
default = Date.today where expression = date_from
default = Date.new(2050,01,01) where expression = date_until

```
CREATE TABLE example(id integer,name text, parameters text); 
INSERT INTO example VALUES



(1,  'Report1','[
  {
    "base_table": "test_table",
    "select_table": null,
    "expression": "p_person_id",
    "aggregate": null,
    "titel_en": "Person",
    "default": null,
    "pflichtfeld": true
  },
  {
    "base_table": "test_table",
    "select_table": null,
    "expression": "date_from",
    "aggregate": null,
    "titel_en": null,
    "default": "Date.new(2000, 01, 01)",
    "pflichtfeld": true
  },
  {
    "base_table": "test_table",
    "select_table": null,
    "expression": "date_until",
    "aggregate": null,
    "titel_en": null,
    "default": "Date.new(2099, 12, 31)",
    "pflichtfeld": true
  },
  {
    "base_table": "test_table",
    "select_table": null,
    "expression": "lg_id",
    "aggregate": null,
    "titel_en": null,
    "default": null,
    "pflichtfeld": true
  }
]'),
(2,  'Report2',null),
(3,  'Report3','[
  {
    "base_table": "another_table",
    "select_table": null,
    "expression": "p_person_id",
    "aggregate": null,
    "titel_en": "Person",
    "default": null,
    "pflichtfeld": true
  },
  {
    "base_table": "another_table",
    "select_table": null,
    "expression": "date_from",
    "aggregate": null,
    "titel_en": null,
    "default": "Date.new(2000, 01, 01)",
    "pflichtfeld": true
  },
  {
    "base_table": "another_table",
    "select_table": null,
    "expression": "date_until",
    "aggregate": null,
    "titel_en": null,
    "default": "Date.new(2099, 12, 31)",
    "pflichtfeld": true
  },
  {
    "base_table": "another_table",
    "select_table": null,
    "expression": "lg_id",
    "aggregate": null,
    "titel_en": null,
    "default": null,
    "pflichtfeld": true
  }
]')
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2fb50633d5f202e27e80aea64ff84d60)

So far i tried this without success

```
update example set parameters = replace(parameters,'  {
    "base_table": "test_table",
    "select_table": null,
    "expression": "date_from",
    "aggregate": null,
    "titel_en": null,
    "default": "Date.new(2000, 01, 01)",
    "pflichtfeld": true
  },
  {
    "base_table": "test_table",
    "select_table": null,
    "expression": "date_until",
    "aggregate": null,
    "titel_en": null,
    "default": "Date.new(2099, 12, 31)",
    "pflichtfeld": true
  },',  {
    "base_table": "test_table",
    "select_table": null,
    "expression": "date_from",
    "aggregate": null,
    "titel_en": null,
    "default": "Date.today",
    "pflichtfeld": true
  },
  {
    "base_table": "test_table",
    "select_table": null,
    "expression": "date_until",
    "aggregate": null,
    "titel_en": null,
    "default": "Date.new(2050, 12, 31)",
    "pflichtfeld": true
  },) where name = 'Report1'
```

Comment: JSON values should be stored in a column defined as `jsonb`

Comment: yes that true, but in this case it's not and i can't change it :(